# Is there a way to have assertPathIs() ignore part of the url?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

While making a Laravel Dusk test function, I am trying to check the path in my application. However the URL in my application changes, depending on the user or what they are looking at (e.g. `/Test/123/testing`: in this case the `123` could be any combination of numbers.)

Is it possible to ignore the middle portion?

```
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
    $browser->loginAs('email@email.com')
            ->visit('/test')
            ->assertPathIs('/test')
            ->assertSee('LinkText')
            ->clickLink('LinkText')
            ->assertPathIs('/test/(CanBeAnything)/testing');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at [the code](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/5.0/src/Concerns/MakesUrlAssertions.php#L158) we can see a regular expression match is actually being performed, after the text is run through [`preg_quote()`](https://www.php.net/preg_quote):

```php
$pattern = str_replace('\*', '.*', preg_quote($path, '/'));
```

This means that you can do a wildcard search by using `*`, so this should work:

```php
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
    $browser->loginAs('email@email.com')
            ->visit('/test')
            ->assertPathIs('/test')
            ->assertSee('LinkText')
            ->clickLink('LinkText')
            ->assertPathIs('/test/*/testing');
});
```